# Create a rich text control field in VBA for Word 2010

Tags: vba, word-2010

I have a control field where I dynamically add certain text. That works well so far. The problem is that in one text I have an input field where the user can type in text.

I need to hardcode the form text input field into the VBA code. How is this achieved? Or can someone point me in the right direction?

In the following code snippet I need to replace the `[InputField]` by a VBA input field.

```
ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Bottom").Item(1).Range.Text = _
"Some Text" & vbNewLine & _
"Some Text" & vbNewLine & _
"Some Text" & vbNewLine & _
"Text [InputField] Text"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by VBA input field. I think you mean "Form Input Field"?
If so that is probably a solution to your problem:

```
Sub TestInsertContentControl()
    Dim m_objRange                      As Range
    Dim m_objRangeInsertTextInput       As Range
    Dim m_objFormField                  As FormField

    Set m_objRange = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Bottom").Item(1).Range
    m_objRange.Text = "Some Text" & vbNewLine & _
    "Some Text" & vbNewLine & _
    "Some Text" & vbNewLine & _
    "Text  "

    Set m_objRangeInsertTextInput = m_objRange
    m_objRangeInsertTextInput.Start = m_objRange.End - 1
    m_objRangeInsertTextInput.End = m_objRange.End

    Set m_objFormField = m_objRangeInsertTextInput.FormFields.Add(Range:=m_objRange, Type:=wdFieldFormTextInput)

    m_objRangeInsertTextInput.Start = m_objFormField.Range.End
    m_objRangeInsertTextInput.End = m_objFormField.Range.End
    m_objRangeInsertTextInput.Text = " Some more Text"
End Sub
```

Comment: By using your code I do not see a form input field. Furthermore I have the problem that I have a 'text [forminput] text' and not only 'text [forminput]'.

Comment: As I wrote, I'm not sure what you mean by InputField. You can check if there a form Inputfield with pressing ALT+F9.
See my edited answer 'text [forminput] text'.

Comment: works very well thank you. Do you know how I can set a Title (an ID so that I can access that field over ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("myField") and how I can set a grey default text which removes itself when the user clicks in? I need to access that field over vba because the 'bottom' content is being locked and therefore I need remove the lock of the specific form input field

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you need. The field in the code above how is being inserted is a "Form Input Field". FormInputFields haven't a Title or ID to set. They also haven't a grey default text to set. Do you need a ContentControl inside your "Bottom" ContentControl?
May you ask a new question and post the link here.